# Jquery find and hide div with duplicate id or html

Tags: jquery, find, hide

I have several div's with same class , so first i want to find which one has duplicate class name and then i want to hide all of the div's except the first one

```
<div class="jquery"> </div> 
 <div class="jquery"></div>
```

Need help please

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[**jQuery's slice**](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) the first element:

```
$('.jquery').slice(1).hide()
```

[**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/MRbEU/2)

---

**EDIT: Find Duplicates**

[**New Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/MRbEU/4/)

```
var duplicated = {},
    class;
$('div').each(function() {
    class = $(this).attr('class');
    duplicated[class] = (duplicated[class] | 0) + 1
})

for (var key in duplicated) {
    if (duplicated.hasOwnProperty(key) && duplicated[key] > 1) {
        $('div.' + key).slice(1).hide()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the additional jQuery call? Isn't `$('.jquery').slice(1).hide() ` enough?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning to new coders that `$('.jquery')` is NOT calling `array.slice()`; it is a jQuery object which happens to have a `.slice()` method of its own -- http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: @mblase, thank you. I've editted. I seriously need more coffee this morning

Answer (score 2):

you should not have multiple `id`s, for class you can do

```
$("div.jquery:not(:first)").hide();
```

or

```
$("div.jquery:gt(0)").hide();
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/674nF/

to find out if there are more than one div with same class name you can do

```
if($(".jquery").length>1){
// more than one divs have class jquery
}
```

to manipulate each div having class `jquery`

```
$(".jquery").each(function(index,j){
$(this).attr("rel","div number"+index);  //this will refer to each respective div having class jquery, for each iteration
});
```

Comment: thank you so much and is there any way to find which div have duplicate class

Answer (score 2):

This won't help you identify which class names are duplicated, but it'll hide the dupes.

```
$('.duplicated_class_name').slice(1).hide()
```

*[edit] added real solution and commentary below:*

```
(function($){

var
  classes = {},
  dupes = {};

$('div')
  .each(function(index, elem){
    $.each(
      elem.className.split(/\s+/),
      function(index, name) {
        if (name) {
          classes[name] = (classes[name] || 0) + 1;
          if (classes[name] > 1) {
            dupes[name] = classes[name];
          }
        }
      }
    );
  });

$.each(
  dupes,
  function(name) {
    $('.' + name)
      .slice(1)
        .hide();
  }
);

})(jQuery);
```

Note: I sincerely doubt you actually want to do this, as it will probably have unintended consequences on your UI.  That is, you will almost certainly hide content that you really want to keep showing.

You almost certainly want to filter which classes are to be hidden, either by providing a predefined whitelist, or at least a matching function of some king (like a regular expression).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.class_name')
```

Will give you a jQuery object containing all the DOM elements with that class. See the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) in the docs.

```
$('.class_name').length
```

The [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property will give you the number of items with that class.

```
$('.class_name').each( function () {
    // do something here...
});
```

Will take one element at once from the elements with the same class, and you can work on each of them at a time. See [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) here. Each of those items have the same class.

```
$('.class_name').slice(1).hide()
```

Will hide all but the first item, because it's removed with [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).